# How can I find the cause of the segfaults I'm receiving from a fresh 17.10 install?

Tags: apt, firefox, 17.10, crash, segmentation-fault

I just installed 17.10 and I'm getting segfault errors from apt as well as Firefox. The two issues might be unrelated, but I haven't been able to come up with a cause.

For apt, I get symptoms that make me think it's this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=773787, but when I attempt the fix from that thread, nothing changes.

For Firefox, tabs will crash every 5-10 seconds, making the browser unusable.

Here are the `dmesg` errors I'm getting:

```
[ 2478.400166] Web Content[14978]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f4792edb5a9 sp 00007ffdb7a02eb0 error 6 in libxul.so[7f478f2ee000+578e000]
[ 2478.445039] apport[15017]: segfault at 400009c79c8 ip 0000000000442f20 sp 00007ffc281b5778 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2478.445051] Process 15017(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2478.445052] Aborting core
[ 2484.833262] Web Content[14620]: segfault at 40000000038 ip 00007fb9c27da91e sp 00007fff07f83910 error 4 in libxul.so[7fb9bfdee000+578e000]
[ 2488.707876] Web Content[15021]: segfault at 16c1b28daec8 ip 00007fc37464c57e sp 00007fff724b9450 error 4 in libxul.so[7fc3708ee000+578e000]
[ 2488.723972] apport[15087]: segfault at 40000000000 ip 00000000004aea95 sp 00007fff0f5c95b0 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2488.723986] Process 15087(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2488.723986] Aborting core
[ 2503.344228] Web Content[13549]: segfault at 7f8e99fe067f ip 0000085dcf11e377 sp 00007ffe10a2e900 error 4
[ 2503.448273] apport[15090]: segfault at 40000000008 ip 0000000000442f20 sp 00007ffe9bdac788 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2503.448286] Process 15090(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2503.448286] Aborting core
[ 2535.174572] apt[15360]: segfault at 40000000020 ip 00007f9f1acb16d9 sp 00007ffe5c183ec0 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.5.0.2[7f9f1abae000+19f000]
[ 2549.462408] apport[15367]: segfault at 40000000000 ip 0000000000472f76 sp 00007fff15da6c60 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2549.462423] Process 15367(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2549.462424] Aborting core
[ 2616.406215] traps: Web Content[15381] general protection ip:b3d469b8f71 sp:7ffdefc6cbb8 error:0
[ 2616.517021] apport[15420]: segfault at 40000000000 ip 0000000000472f76 sp 00007ffe7ed7a300 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2616.517036] Process 15420(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2616.517037] Aborting core
[ 2620.224911] traps: Web Content[15421] general protection ip:b9befdeafef sp:7ffefd6dc4d8 error:0
[ 2624.268095] traps: Socket Thread[15467] general protection ip:7fa11e0f633c sp:7fa112df5ac0 error:0 in libxul.so[7fa11d3ee000+578e000]
[ 2624.382618] apport[15482]: segfault at 40000000000 ip 00000000004b6ab0 sp 00007ffd00ebb470 error 4 in python3.6[400000+3bf000]
[ 2624.382633] Process 15482(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
[ 2624.382634] Aborting core
[ 2651.688998] apt-check[15483]: segfault at 40000000020 ip 00007fe175aed6d9 sp 00007ffe7e3f6770 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.5.0.2[7fe1759ea000+19f000]
```

et cetera.

What can I do to try and track down the root cause of this?

Comment: I'd suggest running the memory check program that is available at grub, first.  The if you can, perhaps pull a single DIMM at a time from your machine, and see if one of the DIMMS has gotten weak or bad.

Comment: Should have thought of that! I ran the pre-boot diagnostics on the machine and found a bad module. Swapped a new one in and it's off to the races! Thanks @CharlesGreen.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @CharlesGreen for the answer:

[How can I find the cause of the segfaults I'm receiving from a fresh 17.10 install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975828/how-can-i-find-the-cause-of-the-segfaults-im-receiving-from-a-fresh-17-10-insta?noredirect=1#comment1565664_975828)

Turns out it was a bad memory module. Anyone in the future reading this should consider running memory diagnostics after reseating your RAM. Then test with combinations of modules taken out and moved around to figure out if it's an issue with one module, one slot, or multiple.

Comment: A nice answer - you might also note that it is not always required to immediately replace bad memory modules - you can block out specific memory segments at boot time - you can point future viewers of this question to [https://askubuntu.com/a/908928/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/908928/283721)